# Determining vector parallel to line

Tags: vectors

Is the vector (2,2,2) +t(0,1,1) parallel to the line (0,0,0)+ t(0,1,1) since the direction is the same but the starting point is different?

Comment: These are both lines, but yes, they are parallel

Comment: Then how do u express the vector parallel to the line (0,0,0)+t(0,1,1)?

Comment: Points, but need to find a vector parallel to the line

Comment: How do I express the vector? In (x,y,z)? Or (x,y,z)+t(a,b,c)?

Comment: So can I say that vector (2,3,3) is parallel to the line (0,0,0) +t(0,1,1)?

Comment: in equation of line: (a,b,c)+t(d,e,f)  : (a,b,c) is a point on line and (d,e,f) is a  vector parallel to line. (a,b,c) is actually a point on line and (d,e,f) just gives a direction. You can basically displace it parallel to itself and put its tail on (a,b,c). Then, by scaling (d,e,f) the head of (d,e,f) gives all points on that line

Comment: A vector is just (x,y,z), whereas a line is (x,y,z) + t(a,b,c)

Comment: So(2,3,3) is correct?

Comment: Vector $m(0,1,1)$ is parallel to the line $(0,0,0)+t(0,1,1)$

Comment: Thank you !!!!!